# SpringMVC @RestController run on a machine but not on the other same configuration machine

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, java-8, spring-tool-suite, spring-4

I am experiencing a weird error. My application is working on one machine but the same URL throws 404 on a different machine having same configuration. The technology suit I am using

Spring4.1.1.6

Apache Tomcat 8.0.37

JDK 1.8_178

My POM is:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.xxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>GeoApi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Geo api</name>

  <properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Missing -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using java based Spring configuration as:

Config.Java

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;  
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;  
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;  
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

        @Configuration //Marks this class as configuration
        //Specifies which package to scan
        @ComponentScan("com.xx.xxxx.api")
        //Enables Spring's annotations 
        @EnableWebMvc   
        public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                  .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

                registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                  .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
            }
        }
```

And

```
    public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  

            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
            ctx.register(Config.class);  
            ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    

            Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
            servlet.addMapping("/");  
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);  

        }  

    }
```

The REST controller looks like:

```
    @RestController
    public class TestRestController {
        @RequestMapping("/sample")
        public String hello(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("name", name);
            return name;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<String[]> listAllUsers(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request ) {
            String[] user = new String[10];
            user[0]= "ram";
            user[1] = "shyam";
            if(user.length <=0 ){
                return new ResponseEntity<String[]>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
                //TODO: discuss if the status has to be HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<String[]>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

The Apache tomcat running with STS, The log difference on application startup are:

Working application:

```
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GeoApi' did not find a matching property.
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Sep 1 2016 10:01:52 UTC
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         8.0.37.0
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            10.0
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\jre
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_72-b15
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         F:\projects\sts-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         F:\Software\sts\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=F:\projects\sts-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=F:\Software\sts\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=F:\projects\sts-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=F:\Software\sts\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\endorsed
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252

    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_72/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_72/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_72/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;F:\projects\Diveling\Softwares\grails-2.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;C:\Users\Rupendra Sharma\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;c:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Rupendra Sharma\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Rupendra Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm;F:\Software\mysql-connector-java-5.1.39;C:\Users\Rupendra Sharma\Desktop\Anil support;F:\Software\sts\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;F:\Software\sts\sts-bundle\sts-3.6.4.RELEASE;;.
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:35 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:35 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1008 ms

    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37

    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:35 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [119] milliseconds.
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:40 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.xx.XXXX.api.configuration.WebInitializer@53e8262c]
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Oct 06, 2016 10:56:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 15719 ms
```

On other machine, where the same URL throws 404 exception:

```
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GeoApi' did not find a matching property.
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Sep 1 2016 10:01:52 UTC
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         8.0.37.0
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Linux
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            3.16.0-77-generic
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /home/claritus/jdk1.8.0_102/jre
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/claritus/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/claritus/apache-tomcat-8.0.37
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/claritus/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/claritus/apache-tomcat-8.0.37
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/claritus/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/claritus/apache-tomcat-8.0.37/endorsed
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read

    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 832 ms

    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37


    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Oct 06, 2016 11:38:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 538 ms
```

I have tried everything to fix the issue:

- Maven clean install
- Project clean
- Running STS on admin mode
- start-stop apache

Comment: Also I am using the JDK1.8 as the Apache JRE. I tried this as a possible fix but it did not work.

Comment: which URL are you trying?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/GeoApi/ with no swagger else http://localhost:8080/GeoApi/swagger-api-doc1.0